# Can different Django apps serve the same URL for different MIME types?

Tags: django, mime-types, dispatcher

I want a URL, say `/users/fred`, to serve different content based on the `Accept` header. If the requested MIME type is `application/activity+json`, I want to serve an ActivityPub representation of Fred's account; otherwise, I want to serve an HTML page.

The twist is that I want to implement the ActivityPub view and the HTML view in different Django apps. If they were at different URLs, this would be easily done with `urls.py`, but that doesn't seem to allow filtering by `Accept`.

Is there a standard way to do this? Do I need to implement something new in middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want that calculation done in the urls.py path itself, no you can't. A url path is linked to a single view function (or View.as_view()). These only apply pattern matching on the url itself.

However, you can certainly link it to a first view function which reads your header and dispatches it to the right app view based on its content.

e.g.
In a urls.py

```
url_pattern = [
    ...
    path('/users/<str:username>', views.user_dispatch_view(), name='user-detail'),
]
```

In app1.views.py

```
from app2.views import json_view

def html_view(request, **kwargs):
    '''
    Do your stuff, or even use a generic view instead,
    calling it with YourGenericView.as_view(request, **kwargs)
    '''

def user_dispatch_view(request, **kwargs):
    if request.Meta.get('Accept') == application/activity+json:
        return json_view(request, **kwargs)
    return http_view(request, **kwargs)
```